# Why can't I access my computer through public IP?

Tags: router, port-forwarding, remote-access

My objective is to access my router settings screen as I type my public IP:
i.e. `188.120.128.130` (not my real IP).
I remember that I could do it a few years ago and for some unknown reason I can't do it right now.

I haven't changed anything significant in my router that I can remember.

I've also tried to enable UPnP and even Port Forwarding port 80 (with both TCP or UDP protocol) to 192.168.1.1 (which is my router local IP), the IPv4/6 Firewall is always turned off.
But so far, nothing seems to be working for me.

I also confirmed that it shouldn't be a problem with my router because of a friend of mine with the same router model on a different city have the same issue and he's using the default settings on his device.

I used [this site](https://canyouseeme.org/) to confirm it, and my only suspicion left is that my ISP is blocking me from using this option.
But then again, how come I can use my BitTorrent client freely if my ISP is blocking me from using all the ports that I want?

My router model is TP-link TD-W9980 if that any help.

Comment: Most of the ISPs do NATing for their users. Are you able to ping your IP from Internet (from ping.eu/ping)?

Comment: @VikasSwami Yes, I Actually can (we're talking about the public IP I hope). So what does it mean?

Comment: Did your ISP assign you that static IP? How did you assign that public IP to your router WAN interface?

Comment: @VikasSwami I don't have a static IP from my ISP, but it shouldn't affect the possibility to use my public IP for a temporary connection.

Comment: Can you access your router settings screen through its LAN IP address, and check what addresses it shows as belonging to itself?

Comment: @grawity The whole point is for me to access it remotely (While I'm not at home).

Comment: That's not what I was asking about.

Comment: @grawity I take back what've I said, I don't know how, but it's actually worked...
But why is that different from what every site of "what is my IP address" showing to me?

Comment: (I was initially wanted to access my Plex server at home)

Comment: It's to confirm that the IP address really got assigned to your local router, and isn't shared between several customers. (In a CGNAT situation, it'd still be seen by websites in exactly the same way, but routing-wise it'd be located outside your router's control.)

Comment: @grawity So what should I do to be able to use the IP that is seen by the websites?

Comment: Are you trying this from your PC. In my case i was trying to access my PC using my public IP and it wasn't working just for me. But it was working for others.